# Problems with PHP connecting to a Java program using a Port

Tags: java, php

Hoping someone can shed some light on this.

I have a PHP program which opens a port and sends some text to a java program listening on that port.  Basically, there could be many instances of this PHP program connecting over this port to this one java program.  The java program contacts an API, retrieves the answer, and then sends the information back over the port to the PHP program.

This solution seems to  work but sometimes I get a empty response in my PHP program.  The java program runs run successfully but the answer string is not transmitted back through the port to the php program.

Does this solution sound valid?  Will I ever have an instance where the java program will send back the wrong information to the PHP program?  Can anyone see any problems here?  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: any reason the PHP app cannot access the API directly?

Comment: yes, we are using PHP4 here and the apapter used to access the API is for PHP5 or Java.  No PHP4 adapter is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Opens a port" is ambiguous, I'm going to assume you mean "opens a TCP connection".

There's no reason that the scheme you outlined cannot work, but you haven't provided enough information to narrow down the cause of the problem you're having.

When your PHP script gets an empty response from your Java code, it could be because the connection was broken, but it's more likely that the code on one end or the other has a bug.  Make sure you're testing all the result values for errors.

If you need help finding the problem, you will need to post more specifics, ideally the smallest example of real code (for both ends of the connection) you can get to exhibit the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I was more interested in determining if this was a valid approach to this problem and, from your reponse, it seems like it is. With this in mind, I will be able to spend some time to determine where in the code the exact bug is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Java program **close** or at least **flush** the socket's stream after writing?

Consult the basic Sun tutorial ["All About Sockets"](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/) for details and proper code examples.

Comment: Yes, it does close the socket's stream after writing.